# How to calculate score based on closeness of two nodes in tree?

Tags: python, postgresql, tree, taxonomy, nested-sets

Let's say I have a tree of categories, where each node in the tree is stored as a row in the database. The approach taken is a [nested set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). A sample tree for a clothing store would be:

```
id | name                             | left_range | right_range
---+----------------------------------+------------+-------------
 0 | Clothing                         |          1 |       22
 1 | Men's                            |          2 |        9
 2 | Suits                            |          3 |        8
 3 | Slacks                           |          4 |        5
 4 | Jackets                          |          6 |        7
 5 | Women's                          |         10 |       21
 5 | Dresses                          |         11 |       16
 5 | Evening Gowns                    |         12 |       13
 5 | Sundresses                       |         14 |       15
 5 | Skirts                           |         17 |       18
 5 | Blouses                          |         19 |       20
```

Let's say I have a shopper looking for suit jackets, and I have three sellers who I might want to recommended to the shopper:

- Seller A sells all clothes, so their node in the tree is `Clothing`
- Seller B sells only men's clothes, so their node is `Men's`
- Seller C only sells suit jackets, so their node is `Jackets`

Since the shopper is looking for suit jackets, their node would also be `Jackets`

How can I rank Seller C highest, since they specialize in suit jackets, followed by seller B, and finally seller A?

Comment: I just wondering because first time I see this model, why dont use parent-child relationship?

Comment: Assume each node also has a parent_id column, which is null for the root node `Clothing`

Comment: But which one you want? because are very different calculations. And can you update the data?

Comment: `order by right_range - left_range`?

Answer (score 0):

I create a table to handling the stores:

```
CREATE TABLE Stores
    ("store_id" int, "name" varchar(13))
;

INSERT INTO Stores
    ("store_id", "name")
VALUES
    ('Seller A', 'Clothing'),
    ('Seller B', 'Men''s'),
    ('Seller C', 'Jackets')
;
```

This is the query:

This compare the store category with every other category to see how specialized is the items. While more specific the items belong to more subcategories and have a higher count.

The stores with Clothing doesnt have anyone so their count is 0.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/FBPUGX70294)**

```
SELECT S1.store_id, COUNT(C2."name")
FROM Stores S1
JOIN Categories  C1
  ON S1."name" = C1."name"
LEFT JOIN Categories  C2  
  ON C1."left_range"  > C2."left_range"
 AND C1."right_range" < C2."right_range"
GROUP BY S1.store_id
ORDER BY COUNT(C2."name") DESC
  ;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: any comment about this answer?